# Some Airflow DAGs Are Writing Logs to S3, Some Are Not

Tags: logging, amazon-s3, airflow

A majority of my DAGs in Airflow (versions 1.10.6 and 1.10.7) are able to successfully upload logs to S3 and I'm able to view these remote logs in the Airflow UI just fine. However, I've got a few DAGs that will not upload DAG logs to S3 upon completed DAG runs (successful or otherwise). It is consistently the same DAGs that exhibit this behavior, but I cannot find any code discrepancies that would prevent DAG logs from being uploaded compared to DAGs that are able to upload logs to S3.

I notice DAGs that do not upload logs to S3 always have end-run records like this:

```
2020-01-29 20:12:06,763 - INFO - Task exited with return code 0 - None
```

Whereas DAGs that do upload logs to S3 have no such log entries. I also see records like the one below across all DAGs, but I see about 2x as many of these messages in DAGs that are not uploading logs to S3:

```
DEBUG - The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
```

Additionally, DAGs that are uploading to S3 have Airflow connection pool/AWS references related to S3 as shown below:

```
[2020-01-29 20:41:32,852] {{connectionpool.py:203}} INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): <IP>
[2020-01-29 20:41:32,895] {{connectionpool.py:735}} INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): <BUCKET>.s3.amazonaws.com
[2020-01-29 20:41:32,932] {{connectionpool.py:735}} INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (2): <BUCKET>.s3.amazonaws.com
[2020-01-29 20:41:32,949] {{connectionpool.py:735}} INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): <BUCKET>.s3.<REGION>.amazonaws.com
[2020-01-29 20:41:32,984] {{connectionpool.py:735}} INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (2): <BUCKET>.s3.<REGION>.amazonaws.com
[2020-01-29 20:41:33,040] {{connectionpool.py:203}} INFO - Starting new HTTP connection (1): <IP>
[2020-01-29 20:41:33,065] {{connectionpool.py:735}} INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): <BUCKET>.s3.amazonaws.com
[2020-01-29 20:41:33,084] {{connectionpool.py:735}} INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): <BUCKET>.s3.<REGION>.amazonaws.com
```

However, the DAGs that are not uploading to S3 have no such entries. Instead they have the following, which are not found in the DAGs that can upload logs to S3:

```
2020-01-29 20:12:06,763 - INFO - Task exited with return code 0 - None
2020-01-29 20:12:06,942 - ERROR - Exception during reset or similar - None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 693, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 880, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 538, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac

Exception ignored in: <function _ConnectionRecord.checkout.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f94e04fa3b0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 503, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 702, in _finalize_fairy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1407, in error
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1514, in _log
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1524, in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1586, in callHandlers
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 894, in handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1126, in emit
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1116, in _open
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
```

I'm not quite sure how to proceed with fixing this. I've tried throwing various darts in the dark unsuccessfully:

- Changing between Airflow versions 1.10.6 and 1.10.7.
- Validated that logs can be shipped to S3 via my own logger library from the Airflow instances across all DAGs, including those where Airflow is unable to upload its own logs to S3.
- Increased sql_alchemy_pool sizes in the airflow.cfg as well as increased cluster hardware as I'd read the psycopg2 operational error can be related to number of connections to the metadata DB.

However none of the above has had any effect on the issue. I'm hesitant to post more detailed log dumps due to sensitive information/credentials/etc. being dumped in the DEBUG logs, but if there is additional information that I can provide, please let me know and I'll do my best to supply it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A logging library we use was improperly configuring root and children loggers which I think was impacting Airflow's logger configuration. Modifying the non-Airflow logging library to configure its own 'root' with children resolved this issue, and a few other logging issues we were experiencing unrelated to Airflow.

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules